# Remove blank lines between patterns

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I wish to remove blank lines(new lines, tabs and spaces) in the file with sed or awk, but only if those blank lines are in between two patterns.

```
lorem lorem PATTERN1

\t

PATTERN2 lorem2 lorem2`
```

I expect the result below which is a concatenation of 2 lines with both patterns.

```
lorem lorem PATTERN1PATTERN2 lorem2 lorem2
```

Comment: sed "/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/d" file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/PATTERN1/!b;:a;/PATTERN2/bb;$!{N;ba};:b;s/(PATTERN1.*)[ \t\n]+(.*PATTERN2)/\1\2/;tb' file
```

- `/PATTERN1/!b` just print the line unless it contains the first pattern
- `:a;/PATTERN2/bb;$!{N;ba}` read subsequent lines into the pattern space (PS) until the second pattern is encountered
- `:b;s/(PATTERN1.*)[ \t\n]+(.*PATTERN2)/;tb` replace all spaces, tabs and newlines between the first and second patterns.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to delete lines that contain only whitespace between lines that contain PATTERN1 and PATTERN2, just do:

```
sed '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/{ /^[ \t]*$/d}'
```

In the sample output you give, it appears that you also want to eliminate the newline that follows PATTERN1, but it's not clear how you want to treat input like:

```
PATTERN1
non-empty-line

PATTERN2
```

nor how you want to handle

```
PATTERN1 non-whitesapce
PATTERN2
```

Perhaps a clarification of the question is needed.  If you really just want to eliminate all whitespace between `pattern1` and `pattern2`, it's probably easiest with:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(pattern1)\s*(pattern2)/$1$2/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

The GNU awk equivalent of @WilliamPursell's perl script:

```
awk -v RS='\0' '{print gensub(/(PATTERN1).*(PATTERN2)/,"\\1\\2","g")}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

@user537723: you could try awk:

---improved previous post, so it prints on one line between the patterns---

```
awk '/PATTERN1/{ORS=x} /PATTERN2/{ORS=RS} ORS || NF' file
```